# OutOfBoundException index:1, size:1

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

i have an outofbound exception index 1, size 1 
i cant seem to find the problem 
here is my code:

```
public void removeSpellToGraveyard(ArrayList<SpellCard> spells){
    for(int c=0; c<5 ; c++ ){
        SpellCard r = spells.get(c);
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
            if(spellArea.get(i) == r){
                graveyard.add(spellArea.remove(i));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like Java to me. If not, please tag your question properly.

Comment: Well presumably `spells.size()` is 1, and you're calling `spells.get(1)` because `c` is `1`. Either that or the equivalent for `spellArea`. Note that the way you're removing items from `spellArea` is pretty dicey - you'll be skipping over values (if you remove element 0, the next element to check is now element 0 again...)

Comment: How you do you `spells.size() >= 5` or `spellArea.size() >= 5`?  You don't check that anywhere.

Comment: Fundamentally though, you haven't told us where the exception is or what you've tried to do to fix it. You haven't given us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, so we're basically left guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide a version of your method which achieves its apparent intent. My hope is that this will at least help you figure out what you wanted to do, if it doesn't solve your issue.

```
public void removeSpellToGraveyard(ArrayList<SpellCard> spells) {
    for (SpellCard r: spells) {
        if (spellArea.remove(r)) {
            graveyard.add(r);
        }
    }
}
```